# Best way to wait app Launch

Tags: objective-c

I have an app that requests from the server some data on xml type. Ok, it does ok.
But seems this action loads a little the app on launching.

```
TBXML *tbxml = nil;
tbxml = [[TBXML tbxmlWithURL:[NSURLURLWithString:@"http://www.someplace.com/test/test.xml"]] retain];
```

So, what i figured is make the app wait to launch completely to do this action. So, i've search for it, and find two ways.

- applicationDidFinishLaunching;
- awakeFromNib;

I dont know if this is the correct way to do this. So, im open to suggestions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I would suggest you to put that XML loading code in a separate thread using NSOperationQueue or NSThread so that it won't block the main thread.

`applicationDidFinishLaunching`, IMHO, should be used to initialize your RootViewController, handle incoming push notifications, local notifications, etc. Use `viewDidLoad` in RootViewController for your purpose.